# An inequality related to matrix norm, inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

The question is that:

We have two matrices $A,B\in \mathbf{C}^{n\times n}$, A is nonsingular and B is singular, let $||\cdot ||$ be $\textbf{any}$ matrix norm, prove

$||A-B||\geq 1/||A^{-1}||$.

My idea is

$||(A-B)||\cdot||A^{-1}||\geq||A^{-1}(A-B)||=||I-A^{-1}B||$

And I am confused here. How to calculate the right side?

$\color{red}{Note:}$ the original question may be wrong when the norm doesn't have sub-multiplicative property. See the comments below.

Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz? I don't see any Cauchy-Schwarz here.  $\|A B\| \le \|A\| \|B\|$ is the sub-multiplicative property, which is (sometimes) taken to be part of the definition of "matrix norm".  Note that for such a norm, if $\|I - C\| < 1$, then $C$ is invertible, namely $C^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (I-C)^j$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry, It seems I have a mistake here. I have fixed it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If $|| \cdot ||$ is a norm, so does $\alpha || \cdot || $, here $\alpha$ is a positive real number. Let $\alpha$ be enough small. I think the inequality will be wrong. Because I get $\alpha^2 ||A-B||||A^{-1}||\geq 1$

Comment: I think for the norm without sub-multiplicative property, the inequality will be wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$B= A+ (B-A) = A\cdot( I - A^{-1}(A-B) ) = A \cdot (I - C)$

where $C = A^{-1}(A-B)$.  Assume that $||A-B||< ||A^{-1}||^{-1}$. Then $||C||\le ||A^{-1} || \cdot ||A-B|| < 1$. Now use the following fact:

If $C$ is a matrix with norm $||C||<1$ then the series $\sum_{n\ge 0} C^n$ is absolutely convergent and its sum is the inverse of $I-C$. In particular: $||C||<1$ implies $(I-C)$ invertible.

Use the above to conclude $B$ is invertible, contradiction.

Comment: Nice, but how can you exclude the possibility of equality i.e. $\|A-B\|\cdot\|A^{-1}\|=1$?

Comment: @CTNT Because we have assumed $||A-B||<||A^{-1}||^{-1}$

Comment: sub-multiplicative property is also used here.  Ops, please also see the comments below my question. There is a discussion about this property.

Comment: @Hans Yes, my comment was dumb. So it holds true for arbitrary sub-multiplicative matrix norms. +1 on this answer

Comment: @CTNT I think you answer is also very inspiring, though just for a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is singular there exists some $v\neq 0$ with $\|v\|=1$  such that $Bv=0$. Thus,
$$\|A-B\|_2^2\geq \|(A-B)v\|^2=\|Av\|^2=v^*A^*Av\geq \lambda_{min}(A^*A)\\ =\lambda_{min}\left[(A^{-1}(A^{-1})^*)^{-1}\right]=\frac{1}{\lambda_{max}(A^{-1}(A^{-1})^*)}=\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|_2^2}$$

**EDIT: For a general induced $p$-norm ($p>1$):** Similarly there exists some $v\neq 0$ with $\|v\|_p=1$  such that $Bv=0$. Thus, for the induced matrix $p$-norm
$$\|A-B\|_p\geq \|(A-B)v\|_p=\|Av\|_p\qquad\qquad(1)$$
Define now $q>0$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Then using Holder inequality
$$\|Av\|_p\|A^{-1}\|_q\geq \|Av\|_p\frac{\|A^{-1}v\|_q}{\|v\|_q}\geq \|v\|_2^2\|v\|_{q}^{-1}\qquad (2)$$
Thus for a general $p$-norm ($p>1$) it holds true from (1), (2) that
$$\|A-B\|_p\geq \min_{v\in Ker(B), \|v\|_p=1} \left\{\|v\|_2^2\|v\|^{-1}_q\right\}\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|_q}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the norm used here is arbitrary

Comment: Actually, if it is arbitrary, the inequality may be wrong

Comment: @Hans Well, I think it might be easy to  generalize the proof  to any induced norm

Comment: @Hans I have edited my answer for general $p$-norms.

Comment: Nice, but there are many other types of norm, I think  Robert Israel's comment and orangeskid's answer are more general.